# Django: Storing db query variables over time and displaying them as graphs

Tags: django

I am building an application that will function as a dashboard. The user will be able to create, update, delete contracts. Part of the contract model looks like this:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
   ...
   contract_date = models.DateField()
   contract_expires = models.DateField(null=True)
   contract_length = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.customer)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.contract_length = (self.contract_expires - self.contract_date).days
       return super(Contract, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I also display the following information about the contracts to each user:

```
contracts_qty = Contract.objects.filter(customer__department__in=[selected_department]).count()
contracts_sum_total = Contract.objects.filter(customer__department__in=[selected_department]).aggregate(Sum('contract_sum'))['contract_sum__sum']
contracts_sum_avg = Contract.objects.filter(customer__department__in=[selected_department]).aggregate(Avg('contract_sum'))['contract_sum__avg']
contract_length_avg = Contract.objects.filter(customer__department__in=[selected_department]).aggregate(Avg('contract_length'))['contract_length__avg']
```

I also want to display the development over time for each of these metrics and for example show the user a graph for each. How do I go about to do this?

I was thinking that perhaps I can create a model with query variables (contracts_qty etc) and use Django Signals to store an instance every time a contract is created, updated or deleted or perhaps automatically save an instance once a month.

Is this the right way to go about this, or am I way off??

Thank you..

Comment: I am thinking that a line graph would be the most appropriate in this case. for example, for contracts_qty, x is time and y is number of contracts. I know how to do the graphing, but not how to get the underlying data.

Comment: I also think you would require a new model to store `time` and respective `total_contracts` values.

Comment: Thank you for your input and suggestion Bijoy. I have already used Bokeh charts in my project and since I am familiar with it I will continue using it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to store calculated fields unless it is the only way to do that, for example, to overtake performances issues. In your case, I don't think you will face performances issues.
What I would do is I would create a django [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/) with the methods necessary to feed you graphs and I would call them into the view time-to-time.
It will be simple, elegant, and easy to scale in case you get more and more ometricsricts to show.